# C# Repeater - Show AlternatingItem template every 3rd item

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have my repeater set up all working fine, but there's a few tweaks i need to make to every third item. my code is below

```
   <asp:Repeater ID="rptItems" runat="server" onitemdatabound="rptItems_ItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            content / html / eval
        </ItemTemplate>
        <AlternatingItemTemplate>
            content / html / eval
        </AlternatingItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

then in my onitemdatabound set up

```
   protected void rptItems_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        // check to see if this is the page to show the form on
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                e.Item.Visible = ((e.Item.Parent as Repeater).Items.Count % 3 == 0);
            }
        }


    }
```

but this doesnt seem to work, it just hides one of the items, any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use item index not Count. Count is static value.

May be something like that:

```
 e.Item.Visible = (e.Item.Index % 3 == 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

use the `RepeaterItem.ItemIndex` instead of `Items.Count`

```
e.Item.ItemIndex % 3 == 0
```

so:

```
e.Item.Visible = e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem &&                       
                                    e.Item.ItemIndex % 3 == 0
```

[read more on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeateritem(v=vs.110).aspx)

remove the Alternating item to do the modifications on every 3th item exclusively.

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rptItems" runat="server" onitemdatabound="rptItems_ItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            content / html / eval
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

And your behind code would be:

```
 e.Item.Visible = e.Item.ItemIndex % 3 == 0
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks Caspar, but only 7 of the 10 items are showing up                 
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
                {
                    e.Item.Visible = e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem && e.Item.ItemIndex % 3 == 0;
                }

Comment: what should be the result then?

Comment: two show all my items (10 currently) but every 3rd item, i will need to use the AlternatingItem template rather than the standard ItemTemplate

Comment: Alternating templates are every OTHER template, so all templates with UNEVEN index, so % 3 crosses % 2 here :) Just don't use the alternating items but ItemTemplate only. Do your mod on these

Comment: does that mean what I'm after isn't possible? i thought there would be a way to bypass the default and change it to what you need. (I'm not a c#,.net developer, im a front end dev, sorry for being such a noob)

Comment: If you want to style every 3th item different, just do it manually and forget the AlternatingItem.

Comment: Ok cheers, one more thing, if i remove the AlternatingItem, then in my itemTemplate, i wrap a div with a certain class on it, can i then hide that div/class on every third item?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106026/discussion-between-caspar-kleijne-and-jordan-sayner).